# How would you integrate $\frac{Si(x)}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

The function $Si(x)$ can be obtained when we integrate 
$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. But how would we go about integrating $\frac{Si(x)}{x}$?

More information about the function $Si(x)$ can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral

Edit: Just checked wolframalpha and even it did not have any answer.

Comment: Is there any reason for believing this antiderivative can be expressed in terms of elementary functions an the sine integral? The antiderivative of $e^x$ can, but the antiderivative of $e^x/x$ cannot.

Comment: $x Si(x) + \cos(x) + C$

Comment: @DaríoA.Gutiérrez That would be the integral for Si(x) and whats with the dislikes?

Comment: I guess you mean an expession with standard (special) functions. Maple gives a result in terms of hypergeometric functions
$$x\,\mathrm{hypergeom}([{\tfrac {1}{2}} , { \tfrac {1}{2}} ], [{ \tfrac {3}{2}}
, { \tfrac {3}{2}} , {\tfrac {3}{2}} ],  - {\tfrac {1}{4}} \,x^{2})
$$
but I guess this is just the Wolfram series in disguise.

Comment: @egreg no I don't have any such reason but then how did we go about defining Si(x) from the integral of (sin(x))/x?

Comment: @RithikKapoor Exactly because the antiderivative of $\sin(x)/x$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @mods I realise this is a relatively new contributer but the title change edit significanlty changes the OP.

Comment: @Kevin I had edited the title when there were no answers and had done it so that there would be no confusion

Comment: I haven't asked the same question twice. If you could maybe read the titles you might see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason for suspecting that the antiderivative of $\operatorname{Si}(x)/x$ can be expressed in terms of “known” functions.

The power series expansion of $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ is
$$
\operatorname{Si}(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\cdot(2n)!}
$$
Therefore the power series expansion of $\operatorname{Si}(x)/x$ is
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)^2\cdot(2n)!}
$$
and therefore the antiderivatives are
$$
c+\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^3\cdot(2n)!}
$$

Note that there is a pattern here: if you start with the function
$$
f_0(x)=x\cos x
$$
then its series expansion is
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}
$$
If we integrate $f_0(x)/x$, we get
$$
f_1(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n)!}=\sin x
$$
(using here and below the antiderivative that evaluates $0$ at $x=0$).

If we integrate $f_1(x)/x$, we get
$$
f_2(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\cdot(2n)!}=\operatorname{Si}x
$$
and so on.

Repeating the process yields
$$
f_k(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^k\cdot(2n)!}
$$
and
$$
Df_{k+1}(x)=\frac{f_k(x)}{x}
$$

Comment: Is the there any way I can see the graph of the integral of (Si(x))/x?

Comment: @RithikKapoor An approximation up to $x^{21}$ is at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5Enx%5E%7B2n%2B1%7D%7D%7B(2n%2B1)%5E3%5Ccdot(2n)!%7D

Comment: Never thought that there would be a pattern here. Good observation.

Answer (score 0):

so, if by definition:
$$\text{Si}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$$
then can we say:
$$I=\int\frac{\text{Si}(x)}{x}dx=\int\frac{\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt}{x}dx=\int\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{tx}dtdx$$
now if we insert a variable:
$$I(y)=\int_0^y\int_0^x\frac{\sin(t)}{tx}dtdx$$
and this may be solvable through change of variables